# Access new python distribution in VS Code terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I have python 3 running on my machine with several versions.

- python 3.6.4 (This runs in my VS Code terminal)
- python 3.9.8 (Anaconda Distribution, Runs in my anaconda terminal)
- python 3.11.4 (My web scraping virtual environment)

I have several virtual environments that I can access via `>Python Select: Interpreter`

[image: Python Select Interpreter]

However in the terminal of my VS Code I can only access `python 3.6.4`.

[image: Python distribution in VS code terminal]

I need to access an updated version of python (at least 3.9, preferably 3.11.4) in order to use the Scrapy package.

How do I change which python version my VS code terminal is accessing by default???

Comment: If you are using the default VS code layout and have configured the python extension for it, there should be a small bar displaying the current python interpreter in the bottom most right corner. The python version will also be displayed there. Just click on it to select the interpreter as per your choice.

Comment: My VS Code shows a loading symbol for my github Copilot extension, however it does not show the python interpreter in the bottom right of VS Code.

Comment: Then you either dont have the python extension installed or is an interpreter selected. In the latter case, you can still click over it and select an interpreter.

Comment: i currently have the python extension installed (the microsoft version). However when i click the bottom right of my VS code nothing happens. 

i also tried activating a virtual envieonment I have created in my Anaconda prompt but it ia not accessible theough the cli interface.

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python version displayed in the lower right corner of the vscode interface and `Python: Select Interpreter` features are all extended for **Python**. The vscode terminal uses the system terminal. If you type `python` directly, it will use the python environment configured in the environment variable `path` just like the system Power Shell or CMD.

**The following methods are for your reference:**

- Configure the system environment variable `path` and add the path to the python interpreter you want to use.
- You can use the full path to open the python environment you want to use.

  [image]
- [Create a virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_creating-environments) using the new version, then select the virtual environment interpreter in vscode and create a new terminal.

*I recommend using the third method, which is simpler and easier to use.*